# Switch between 3 states?

Tags: led, pcb-design

I would like to create a circuit board that can toggle between 3 states, only with the press of a button.

So when pressing the button, the board should go to the next state, and at the last state, should loop back to the first.

The 3 states are like this, using 2 LEDs:

1. LED 1 is on, LED 2 is off
2. LED 1 is off, LED 2 is on
3. Both LEDs are off

Can I create a simple circuit board that can do this? If so, how would it be designed?

(Disclaimer: I only know high-school electronic stuff, but I can solder pretty well)

Comment: Can you use microcontrollers?

Comment: Yes, but I'd like to keep it simple and compact, so no arduino things.

Comment: Use PIC16F84 or similar. Use switch statement in C and your problem is solved.

Comment: Use a 3 bit shift register (eg part of 74LS95). Initialise it to 001 with a 'power on reset' to force parallel load - first and second bit drive your LED's third bit feeds back to DS1 (serial input) - use your button (de-bounced) to provide the 'clock'

Comment: @Icy: I suggest you move that to an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A 4017 decade counter will do the job.  No LED on output 0, LED 1 on output 1, LED 2 on output 2 and reset connected to output 3.
You could base it on the first circuit here - http://www.clarvis.co.uk/version2/4017.html

Answer (score 4):

Use a 3 bit shift register (eg part of 74LS95).

Initialise it to 001 with a 'power on reset' to force parallel load - a capacitor / resistor on the pin will do this.

Use the first and second bit outputs to drive your LED's. feed the third bit back to DS1 - the serial input

You will need to de-bounce the button - probably using a simple RC filter - and use that to provide the 'clock' to shift the signal on.